# java LDAP read timeout when timeout is not reached?

Tags: java, sockets, ldap, timeout

I have a Java application that connects to an LDAP using LDAPContext. Below are my environment properties:

```
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", READ_TIMEOUT);
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, host);
    if (principal == null || principal.isEmpty()) {
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
    } else {
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal + "@" + domain);
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    }
    if (useLDAPS) {
      env.put(Context.SECURITY_PROTOCOL, "ssl");
    }
```

The problem I have been encountering lately is every once in a while when attempting to connect, I get a read timeout error before the timeout time has been reached. The timeout is set to 10000ms (10 seconds). I have even tried removing the property that sets the timeout and it still occurs.

Are there other reasons this could be happening? If the connection gets reset due to something like max connections being reached, does it throw a read timeout? The exception I am seeing is:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: XX.XX.XX.XX:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
        at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:226)
```

**Update 9/15/15**
Still having this issue. Here is the stack trace. Any help is appreacited.

```
WARNING: CommunicationException
javax.naming.CommunicationException: XX.XX.XX.XX:636 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:226)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.<init>(LdapClient.java:136)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1608)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2698)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:316)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:193)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:211)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
       at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
       at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
       at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
       at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:153)
       at my.package.name.ToolClass.getLdapConnection(ToolClass.java:302)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
       at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
       at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:442)
       at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:480)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:934)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.createSocket(Connection.java:381)
       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:203)
       ... 27 more
```

Comment: Post the stack trace.

Comment: @EJP I added the stack trace. Still having this issue.

Comment: What version is your JVM? There used to be a bug where the read timeout did not work over SSL.

Comment: @Manjunath That bug refers to a bug in a *test*, not in the JDK.

Comment: @BrianOchs JVM is 1.7.0_80

Comment: This bug doesn't appear to be in a test, but in the JDK. http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7094377 . Am I missing something in the bug report?

Comment: @BrianOchs I saw that report too, but it looks like it was resolved in 1.6, so my JVM should have the fix...